# Ignore ConnectionError while scraping

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, multiprocessing, tqdm

so I have a DataFrame containing 60k urls and I'm using beautifulsoup scrape the data from each of these urls. I've used tqdm and multiprocessing to increase the speed of scraping, but some urls are giving me a ConnectionError, which is fine. I'd like to know how to ignore such links and move on to the next one without disrupting my tqdm progress.

```
import tqdm
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


pool= Pool(10)
list_data= list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap(scrape_data_function, df['url'].to_list()), total= len(df['url'])))
pool.terminate()
pool.close()
```

I've tried using try and except, but everytime a faulty url comes up, the try block runs again and the scraping starts from the first link all over again on tqdm.

This is my scraping function:

```
def scrape_data_function(url):
    page= requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 5)
    soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    data= soup.find_all("div", {"class": 'post-body'})
    heading= soup.find("h1").getText()
    count= 1       
    try:
        dict_row= {"url": url, "data": heading + str([i.get_text(separator= " ") for i in data])}
        return dict_row
    except:
        print(url)
```

TIA.

Comment: You will have to put a try/catch inside the `scrape_data_function`

Comment: can you tell me how? there's already an except clause in my function that should ignore the ConnectionErrors

Comment: It seems like your try/catch does not actually cover the `requests.get`, which is where the error is generated

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Now the function will return the same dictionary either way but the data field will be a string capturing the exception that was raised. You could add a key/value pair for "error":True/False and save that too, so that you can filter by error or not error in the resulting dataframe.

```
def scrape_data_function(url):
    try:
        page= requests.get(url, headers = headers, timeout= 5)
        soup= BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        data= soup.find_all("div", {"class": 'post-body'})
        heading= soup.find("h1").getText()
        count= 1       
        dict_row= {"url": url, "data": heading + str([i.get_text(separator= " ") for i in data])}
        return dict_row
    except Exception as e:
        s = str(e)
        dict_row= {"url": url, "data": s }
        return dict_row
```